# Ok to call document.querySelector( ) a bunch

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

If I have multiple instances of the following lines of code through out my `js` file:

```
document.querySelector('#IdName').play(); 
document.querySelector('#IdName').pause();
```

Is it a good idea to create a function and pass it the `IdName`(IdName will change in various parts of the code)? I know what it does but I'm really just curious if it's a good practice to call `document.querySelector(  )`a bunch of times in the file or put it in a function where I only call it twice to perform the `play` and `pause` actions.

Comment: for readability, yes, but performance wise it isn't different enough to matter.

Comment: Find the relevant elements once and then bind event handlers to them to toggle between play/pause states. Or use event delegation, but repeatedly finding an element isn't all that expensive, just a little redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good practice to write code that is reusable, so in that case a function is better practice. If the function only contains 1 line of code and you call it many times, it is still preferable because then if you ever decide to update that line of code or add more code, it's centralized and you change in one place only.

As far as actual execution is concerned, these are the same:

```
document.querySelector('#IdName1').play(); 
document.querySelector('#IdName1').pause();
document.querySelector('#IdName2').play(); 
document.querySelector('#IdName2').pause();
document.querySelector('#IdName3').play(); 
document.querySelector('#IdName3').pause();
```

vs

```
playpause("#IdName1");
playpause("#IdName2");
playpause("#IdName3");

function playpause(idname){
  document.querySelector(idname).play(); 
  document.querySelector(idname).pause();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Along with adeneo this is what I was going for! New to `js` so trying t learn how to write good code so thankks again!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a high enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

If you constantly need the same element, change the function to take a DOM node, and store the element in a variable instead

```
function doStuff(elem) {
    elem.play();
}

function stopStuff(elem) {
    elem.pause();
}

var element = document.querySelector('#IdName');

doStuff( element );

// later

stopStuff( element );
```

That way you only get the element once, and avoid unneccesary DOM lookups

Comment: Yes. This was the way that I thought about doing it but wasn't sure if it was necessary. Really concerned with creating good clean code that is efficient (although efficiency isn't affect all that much in this case as I just read. lol)

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to cache that query in a variable so you don't need to search the DOM each time.

For an ID selector this time saving is likely minimal but for more complex collections can help

```
var $el = document.querySelector('#IdName');
$el.play();
$el.pause();
```

Comment: what if the `IdName` changes dynamically?

Comment: Some people use a simple jQuery like function `var $ = function(selector){ return document.querySelector(selector);}` ... then you can do `var $el = $('#IdName')`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Steve's answer, also note that if you are using the same one twice in a row:

```
document.querySelector('#IdName').play(); 
document.querySelector('#IdName').pause();
```

then it is a better practice to do:

```
var thing_with_play_and_pause = document.querySelector('#IdName');
thing_with_play_and_pause.play();
thing_with_play_and_pause.pause();
```

This reduces the number of queries you have to make. Some IDEs (PyCharm for instance) will complain if you don't because it is less efficient.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me as well